# JQuery Validated Form Not Submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form that I am using on my site and it is validated with some simple JQuery validation. Problem is it's not submitting or doing anything really when I change the values.  Here is my code:

```
<form id="radForm" method="post" action="events.php?type=rad">
    <div class="searchBoxLeft searchBoxRad"></div>
    <div class="searchBoxMiddle">
        <input id="radSearch" type="text" class="searchBoxInput searchBoxShort" value="<?php echo $yourradius; ?>" />
        <label class="searchBoxLabel">Mile Radius of Your Address</label>
    </div>
    <div id="radButton" class="searchBoxRight"></div>
    <div class="clearLeft"></div>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var radsearchok = 0;
        //Rad search
        $('#radSearch').blur(function()
        {
            var radsearch=$("#radSearch").val();
            if(radsearch < 2){
                $('#radSearch').addClass("searchError");
                radsearchok = 0;
            }
            else if(radsearch > 50){
                $('#radSearch').addClass("searchError");
                radsearchok = 0;
            }
            else{
                $('#radSearch').addClass("searchSuccess");
                radsearchok = 1;
            }
        });
        // Submit button action
        $('#radButton').click(function()
        {
            if(radsearchok == 1)
            {            
                $("#radForm").submit();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#radSearch').addClass("searchError");
            }
            return false;
        });
        //End
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this?

Comment: [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns a string -> [`.parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) will be your friend here :)

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I've edited the code. Still doesn't fix my original problem though. I've used this same script several times with no problems but this time it's just not working and I can't figure out why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zdeZ2/1/ - made some changes and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back and set the .val() property again of your form, otherwise it will take the original value of .val() not `radsearch`;

Not sure if you actually want to update .val() though or just attach a property. Some options:

Right before the closing brace of .blur --> }); add"

`$("#radSearch").val(radsearch);`

Or:

Add a hidden input to your form with a new ID like:

`<input type='hidden' name='radsearchHidden' />`

and then do the same before the end of .blur:

`$("#radsearchHidden").val(radsearch);`

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code (http://jsfiddle.net/zdeZ2/2/) which I'll describe below:

`<div id="radButton" class="searchBoxRight"></div>` I assume you have something in there=> `<input id="radButton" class="searchBoxRight" type="button" value="rad button">`

I rewrote your validator with blur as follows. As suggested it coroses the radSearch value to an integer before comparisions The changes remove the `searchError` and `searchSuccess` classes before validating. I also made some optimizations for you.

```
//Rad search
$('#radSearch').blur(function () {
    //remove classes from previous validating
    var $this = $(this).removeClass("searchError").removeClass("searchSuccess");
    var radsearch = $this.val() | 0; //radsearch is an integer
    if (radsearch < 2 || radsearch > 50) {
        $this.addClass("searchError");
        radsearchok = 0;
    } else {
        $this.addClass("searchSuccess");
        radsearchok = 1;
    }
});
```

Can be equivalently written as:

```
//Rad search
$('#radSearch').blur(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var radsearch = $("#radSearch").val() | 0; //radsearch is an integer
    var valid = radsearch < 2 || radsearch > 50;

    $this.toggleClass("searchError", !valid)
        .toggleClass("searchSuccess", valid);
    radsearchchok = valid ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the JSFiddle and description. I've tried everything you said but it's still not working. I ran my original code through JSFiddle for the css errors and it works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/cL87R/

Comment: So then whats the problem?

Comment: That's what I want to know. Jquery is working fine on my site but this code will not work, even though there are no problems in JSFiddle

Comment: @user2737457 are all the `[id]` properties you're using in this snippet unique on the page?

Comment: Yes they were. I found that the problem was actually an unused snippet of JQuery code that I had at the top of my page (Relating to Fancybox) was preventing the form validation code from running properly. As soon as I deleted it the forms worked fine again. Thanks for your help and suggestions though